# Global bash alias from script

Tags: bash, alias

I'd like to create alias by script, and use it in bash.

Namely:

```
#!/bin/bash
alias mycmd="ls -la"
```

Bash:

```
login@host ~$: ./script
login@host ~$: mycmd
*ls output*
```

Of course, alias should be available just for one session (not .bashrc etc).
Is it possible? Unfortunately I have not found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way to do is to *source* the script rather than running it.

```
source myscript.sh
mycmd
```

Answer (score 5):

```
login@host ~$: . ./script
login@host ~$: mycmd
```

Will execute it in your shell I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script to do the job, and put it in a bin directory on your PATH (probably $HOME/bin):

```
$ echo "exec ls -la \"\$@\"" > $HOME/bin/mycmd
$ chmod 555 $HOME/bin/mycmd
$
```

This is utterly reliable if you actually set PATH to include $HOME/bin.

(Of course, we can debate the merit of typing 5 letters instead of 6 characters, but I assume the names are illustrative rather than real.)

Comment: @sigo: your call; I'd rather do it that way than using (new-fangled things like) aliases.  I have one alias not set by the shell itself; that provides me with the 'r' (for 'repeat') command that was available in 'ksh'.  Anything else is a script in my bin directory.